# Extend displays no longer working after Win 10 update

Tags: display-settings

After a recent Windows 10 update my 2nd monitor is no longer working. I get a blank screen and it responds to Extend these Displays by lighting up and showing the HDMI input for few seconds, but I never see the screen. Windows says the driver is the latest, but maybe need to roll back to an earlier version, but not sure how to do that. It is an Intel video card. Tried rebooting, tried restarting the monitor, etc. with no luck.

Comment: Rolling back is a bad idea.  Instead try updating it by using the Intel tools